# Are there any open source block explorer available?

Tags: block-explorer

If so, can a link to their source code please be provided?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is the [Onion Monero Blockchain Explorer](https://github.com/moneroexamples/onion-monero-blockchain-explorer). The README says it's open source but no license is explicitly mentioned.